# Print The Input Backward

Tags: code-golf, string

Just take an input in any way and then print it backward (trailing newlines allowed). For example:

```
Hello World -> dlroW olleH
Hi -> iH
```

Yes, it is case sensitive. Shortest code wins

Comment: Please do take some time to check for extremely similar challenges. FWIW [Jelly 1 byte: `Ṛ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzln///9X8gDy8hXC84tyUpQA)

Comment: As well as being a duplicate, this is underspecified. What may the input contain? What should happen if we get Newlines?

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
StringReverse
```